# Retrieve all WooCommerce products without image that are in stock via SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I use this query sql to retrieve all products without image

```
SELECT id
FROM   `wp_posts` 
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE  `meta_key` = 
'_thumbnail_id') 
AND `post_type` = 'product' 
AND `post_status` = 'publish'
```

Now I would retrieve all products without image and stock status in stock, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following SQL Query will allow you to retrieve products without image that are "In stock":

```
SELECT ID
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN  wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
AND p.post_type = 'product'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status'
AND pm.meta_value = 'instock'
```

Or you can query it using `WPDB` Class through php like:

```
global $wpdb;

$product_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT ID
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
    INNER JOIN  {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
    AND p.post_type = 'product'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status'
    AND pm.meta_value = 'instock'
");

// Raw output
print_r($product_ids);
```